# Retrieving date from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have mysql datatype as date, my date format in database is `20/1/2015`. Now I wish to retrieve data using date.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Device_Count where Date='20/1/2015' 
GO
```

I am getting error like:
`Incorrect date value: '20/1/2015' for column 'Date' at row 1`

Please find and post the status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL's date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

change your query as below and it should work, provided your `Date` column data type is `date`.

```
SELECT * FROM Device_Count where Date=STR_TO_DATE('20/1/2015', '%d/%m/%Y' )
```

**Refer to Documentation**:
[***STR_TO_DATE(str,format)***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Check your date format and compare it by the same format

Answer (score 0):

Date is stored in MYSQL in the format of YYYY-mm-dd. Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Device_Count where Date='2015-01-20'
GO
```